# Fourier transform with initial limit starting from 0

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For a function $f(p)$, the Fourier transform is $\hat{f}(p)=\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}e^{-i xp}f(x)dx$. What are the conditions that i write it as; $\hat{f}(p)=2\int_{0} ^{\infty}e^{-ixp}f(x)dx$? I think if $f(x)$ is even then I can write it. Or is it even possible to write such that initial limit starts from 0?

Comment: The _integrand_ $e^{-ixp} f(x)$ must be even in order to halve the length of the integral and double.

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dx =2 \int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ if you know that $g$ is even. Since here $g(x) = e^{-ixp} f(x)$,   the property you would need for this conclusion is 
$$
e^{-ixp}f(x) = e^{ixp} f(-x)
$$
which unfortunately doesn't hold unless $f\equiv 0$ (considering that $p$ is arbitrary).

However, if $f(-x) = \overline{f(x)}$, it follows that 
$$
\overline{e^{-ixp}f(x)} = e^{ixp} f(-x)
$$
and therefore
$$
\operatorname{Re}\hat f(p) = 2\operatorname{Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-ixp} f(x)\,dx
$$
This is particularly useful when $\hat f(p)$ is known to be real; a typical scenario in which this happens is taking the inverse Fourier transform related to the Fourier transform of a real function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I really appreciate that